# Regex To Match Order Of String

Tags: regex

I wanted to match the words in string with reverse order.

We wanted to put validation to prompt user, if name exists in reverse order.

**For example:**

If `name` column has the value, 'Viral,Tennis'

Now if user enters a new name with the value, 'Tennis,Viral'

Then how can we match reverse order of word using regex or some other way?

I am using C#.net for development.

Comment: What do you mean by *match reverse order of word*?

Comment: Pehaps, can you add the language you are using?

Comment: I think that you would be better off splitting the string and iterate over it in reverse.

Comment: I Can split the string but the problem with split character , their could be string like (Viral Tennis,Viral.Tennis,Viral_Tennis) , how could we consider split character ?

Comment: See my answer below. You could add/remove delimeters from your regular expression. The example I have posted will split whenever a white space is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [Regex.Split(String input, String regex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) and do something like so:

```
String[] userEntry = Regex.Split(userString, "\\s+");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
for (int i = userEntry.Length -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     sb.append(userEntry[i]).append(" ");
}

String result = sb.ToString();
//Do Validation
```

That would do the trick, however, you need to keep in mind that things will get a little bit messy if you do not want to change the order of special symbols such as the comma. You could easily remove those and do any validation without special symbols.

EDIT: It depends on what you mean by special symbols. The regex `[^a-zA-z0-9]+` will match any character which is not a letter (upper or lower case) and which is also not a number. So you could easily do something like so:

```
  string input = ...
  string pattern = "[^a-zA-z0-9]+";
  string replacement = "";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

The above should yield a string which is only made from letters and digits. White spaces will also be removed.

Comment: Is there  any Regex to remove special symbols?

Comment: @Viral: I have modified my answer. If you have any symbols which you do not want to be removed just add them to the `pattern` variable, making sure that they are within the square brackets.